# Trying to refactor this to LinQ but getting a invalid cast

Tags: c#, linq

So I am wanting to refactor this to LinQ, and not having any luck with it and I am out of search options to guide me in the right direction.

Can someone explain this to me please, as the commented code works and the LinQ well I know I am doing it wrong. Just can't find any information to guide me along.

```
    public static T Get<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (IsRegistered(type))
        {
            //foreach(var service in _services)
            //{
            //    var test = service.InstanceClass;

            //    if(test.GetType().Equals(type))
            //    {
            //        return (T)test;
            //    }
            //}

            return (T) _services.Select(x => x.InstanceClass.GetType() == type);
        }

        return default;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to return `T`, not `bool` that's why the final `Select` is *incorrect*:

```
// Returns `bool`: if "x.InstanceClass" is of type "type"
Select(x => x.InstanceClass.GetType() == type)
```

Now let's state the problem:

1. From `_services` we want to return *first* `service.InstanceClass` which is of `type` type
2. If there are no such items, return default

We can do it like this:

```
return _services
  .Select(item => item.InstanceClass) 
  .OfType<T>()
  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetType() == type);
```

A brief explanation on what's going on:

- We should return some `item.InstanceClass` from `_services` so put `Select`.
- We are interesting in `InstanceClass` which can be treated as in instance of type `T` - that's a purpose of `OfType<T>()`.
- Finally, we want `InstanceClass` to be exaclty of type `T` (and not say, of a derived type) and we put `FirstOrDefault` with condition.

The method can look like this:

```
public static T Get<T>() {
  // Let's check first for special and edge cases
  if (!IsRegistered(typeof(T)))
    return default;

  return _services
   .Select(item => item.InstanceClass) 
   .OfType<T>()
   .FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetType() == typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea that I was returning a bool. So that would explain the invalid cast then. Now that you have stated that, I can now actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable<bool>` and you're casting it to `T`, so make sure you using `Where` and do a `FirstOrDefault()` to get only out value.

Try this:

```
return (T)_services.Where(x => x.InstanceClass.GetType() == type).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sorry, but `Select(x => x.InstanceClass.GetType() == type)` returns `bool`, not `T` and the result returned will be `bool` as well. That's why the code will not compile. You may want to change `Select` to `Where` or move condition into `FirstOrDefault` and add a cast.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I should have picked up on that.